# How to give null value to a parameter when using @FileParameters of JUnitParams

Tags: java, junit, junitparams

I try to use FileParameters annotation of JUnitParamsRunner. I cannot give null to a variable. The code and test file is below.

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PasswordCheckerFileParameterizedTest {


    @Test
    @FileParameters("src/test/resources/testScenarios.csv")
    public void checkPasswordIsValid_checkMultipleCase(String password,boolean expectedResult){
        PasswordChecker passwordChecker = new PasswordChecker();
        assertEquals(expectedResult,passwordChecker.checkPasswordIsValid(password));
    }
}
```

testScenarios.csv

```
,false
sD1.,false
ssfdsdfsdf234.,false
SEWERWER234.,false
ssfdsdfsdSDFSDF.,false
ssfdsdfsdSDFSDF3234,false
ssfdsdfsdSDFSDF23.,true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work by default since `FileParameters` uses [`IdentityMapper`](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/main/java/junitparams/mappers/IdentityMapper.java) to map lines in the file to parameters and that works as if you used the `@Parameters({"aaa,bbb", "ccc,ddd"}` syntax in which you cannot provide a `null` value - writing `null` will give you a String saying `"null`".

You can however provide your own mapper by means of `FileParameters#mapper`. It has to return a mapped `Object[][]` (same format as if you used a method parameter provider for `@Parameters(method = ...)`). Then you need to decide in what way you'll mark `null` in your file.

A sample mapper that treats the string `"xxx"` as a `null` marker would look like this:

```
public class XxxToNullMapper implements DataMapper {
    @Override
    public Object[] map(Reader reader) {
        return new BufferedReader(reader).lines()
                .map(line -> line.split(","))
                .map(columns ->
                        Stream.of(columns)
                                .map(column -> column.equals("xxx") ? null : column)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray()
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
@FileParameters(
        value = "/test.csv",
        mapper = XxxToNullMapper.class
)
public void xxxIsNullFileParameters(String a, String b) {
    System.out.println("Params are: " + a + " (is null? " + (a == null) + "), " + b + " (is null? " + (b == null) + ")");
}
```

**`/test.csv`**:

```
aaa,bbb
aaa,xxx
```

Prints

```
Params are: aaa (is null? false), bbb (is null? false)
Params are: aaa (is null? false), null (is null? true)
```

Answer (score 13):

I haven't used `@FileParameters` but for normal `@Parameters` you can use [the @Nullable annotation](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/f6054496cba243e7dd9b6f13f5f34de2f808e575/src/main/java/junitparams/converters/Nullable.java):

```
@Test
@Parameters({"null, , null"})
public void yourTest(@Nullable String nullable, String blank, String textIsNull) {
  //  important part ^^^^^^^^^         but no @Nullable here ^^

  assertThat(nullable).isNull();         // it worked!
  assertThat(blank).equals("");
  assertThat(textIsNull).equals("null"); // not null but the string "null"
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best solution. I tried it and it worked perfectly.